# React onClick Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu in React, and I don't understand why the onClick event listener in the return is not working. The menu is loading as expected initially with no dropdown visible, however when I click on the  class nothing happens.

```
var NavLinkContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      listVisible: false
    };
  },
  show: function(){
    this.setState({
      listVisible: true
    });
  },
  hide: function(){
    this.setState({
      listVisible: false
    });
  },
  generateItem: function(item){
    return <NavLink bold={item.bold} key={item.id} url={item.url} text={item.text}/>
  },
  render: function(){
    var items = this.props.items.map(this.generateItem);
    var visible = this.state.listVisible;
    var listClass;
    if (visible){
      listClass = 'navlinkcontainer';
    } else {
      listClass = 'navlinkcontainer hide'
    }
    return (
      <ul className={listClass} onClick={this.show}>
        {items}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: What version of React are you using? You may need `this.show.bind(this)`.

Comment: dont need to bind this, since show is in the same scope

Comment: Ya that's what I thought, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: are you possibly "tapping" it? This happens when you emulate phone device in your browser

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean? I am working in my browser though, from a localhost server.

Comment: okay never mind... try adding "li { pointer-events: none; }" to your css

Comment: I am assuming that you are having your li elements "covering" you ul element. This means that your li elements block your click.

Comment: dont render your items and just type some text into your ul tag and check if that works

Comment: I removed the {items} from the render, and just rendered a random string, but the onClick still did not work

Comment: strange.... somehow you are not clicking the DOM element. It might be covered up by something with z-index?

Comment: I think that is the error, since the list is set to not visible initially, I can't click it, so I need to move the onClick into my parent component. Now I am just confused about how I can use the onClick in the parent component to trigger a function in the child.

Comment: first ask yourself if that is really neccessary. Is your component really a reusable component or does it acctually make sence implmeneting it into the parent. If it makes sence keeping this component then you might have to work with ref's. In your parent component you will have to add the ref attribute to your NavLinkContainer. See this link https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: The component is reused many times in my menu. I believe I have to put the implementation of the onClick into my parent so that I can click it in the DOM. Right now, I am trying an implementation which stores the value of listVisible in the parent state as a prop in NavLinkContainer, so that this value can be accessed during the rendering of NavLinkContainer. Is this a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

onClick is working fine, and there is nothing wrong with your `show` function. You can see in this bin that the function is getting called and the state is updating appropriately: 
http://jsbin.com/dazonovowi

You probably have a problem with your CSS, so check that first, and then check whether any child components are rendering improperly. A good way to solve your CSS problem: try setting listVisible to `true` in your getInitialState and design how the component should look fully expanded, then set it back to `false` when you're ready to test the functionality again.